# How to select a native monospace font in theme.css?

Tags: codenameone

I'm trying to select a native monospace font on the device (iOS, but also Android), but I can't find any information in the CN1 documentation on how to do this. Is it actually possible, and if not, any tips for work-arounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there was a regression that caused system fonts to never be used.  I have just posted a fix that will be available in friday's update.  The syntax is normal CSS syntax:

```
MyStyle {
    font-family: monospace;
}
```

Comment: Great, I did try this a long time ago, but it didn't work so I assumed it wasn't the right way. I'll test it after Friday.

Comment: Small add-on question: so far I've used for example `font-family:  native:MainRegular"` - if I want to use a monospace font of the same size, is there a way to find out what size each native font like "native:MainRegular" is on a specific OS?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for fonts is [here](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/theme-basics.html) when using the designer and [here](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/css.html) when using css.

You can pick any ttf file as a font and place it in the right location (src directory). You can then use it from the style or from the code. If you have a monospace TTF file you can use that.

Comment: Thanks, but I was hoping there was a way in CSS to access *native*/system monospace fonts, like the ones I assume you get when you use  Font.createSystemFont(Font.FACE_MONOSPACE, Font.STYLE_PLAIN, Font.SIZE_SMALL)?

Comment: I'm not sure what the syntax for that would be, I'll need to check

Comment: Thanks, that would be great. I've read the CN1 doc, and googled to see if I could find any examples, but no luck so far. I'd also be interested if it is documented which specific fonts are picked on each platform - I tried looking in the CN1 sources, but didn't manage to find where those details are.

Comment: The system fonts are implemented very differently than the truetype fonts. So we have no control over which font they use. The best answer to that would be whatever is built in.

Comment: Thanks, but I asked the question because the documentation you link to,doesn’t seem to explain *how* to refer to system fonts in CSS? The documentation says “You can use system fonts” but not how and nomexamples. I tried various ways, but couldn’t find any that worked.